# Вывести несколько значений из запроса в одну переменную

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица `cred`:

```
| parent_id | id    | clientID |
+-----------+-------+----------+
|           | 28741 | 28850    |
| 28741     | 28611 | 28850    |
| 28741     | 28612 | 28850    |
|           | 28742 | 28850    |
```

Мне нужно записать в переменную  `vc_credits`  2 `id`, где `parent_id` пустой.
Мой запрос:

```
begin  
    select id  into vr_cr from cred
    where clientID = 28850 and parent_id  is null
exception when too_many_rows then 
    vc_credits : = vr_cr||','||vr_cr;  
end;
```

Ожидаемый результат  в переменной: `vc_credits = 28741,28742`.

Comment: так у вас ничего не выйдет. если использовать такой подход, то нужно делать цикл по записям и добавлять в переменную значения на каждой итерации. Но проще воспользоваться функцией listagg, которая сама соберет список через запятую и запрос вернет ровно одну строку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так можно в цикле с неявным курсором:

```
declare vc_credits varchar2 (32676); begin  
    for r in (
        select id  
        from cred
        where clientID = 28850 
        and parent_id  is null
        ) loop vc_credits := vc_credits||','||r.id; end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line ('result='||ltrim (vc_credits,',')); 
end;
/
```

Или одним запросом без цикла:

```
select listagg (id, ',') within group (order by id) res  
from cred
where clientID = 28850 
and parent_id  is null   
;
RES                                                                            
-----------------
28741,28742
```

---

А так одним запросом в одну переменную:

```
declare vc_credits sys.odciNumberList; begin  
    select id bulk collect into vc_credits  
    from cred
    where clientID = 28850 
    and parent_id  is null
    ;
    for r in (
        select * from cred c
        join table (vc_credits) t on t.column_value = c.id
        ) loop dbms_output.put_line ('credit id='||r.id); end loop;
end;
/

credit id=28741
credit id=28742
```

Comment: первый запрос возвращает данные с запятой ,28741,28742          substr не помогает , как можно вывести желаемый результат

Comment: @Zhandos Уже обновил, проверте.

Comment: в след. Цикле пытаюсь найти данные, но при  приравнении возвращается ошибка. Делаю так        id in(vc_credits), ORA-01722 неверное число, через to_number не получается, буду блогодарен.

Comment: Так не получится.  Оператор IN ожидает чисел через запятую, а не строку в которой есть запятая. Вам надо посмотреть в сторону динамических запросов или возможно как во другом ответе, join с вложенной таблицей.

Answer (score 2):

Переменная `vr_cr`  может хранить только 1 значение. Если это `Number`, то можно объявить ее как коллекцию например:

```
type numberstype is table of number; 
vr_cr numberstype;`
```

и потом выводить все нужные значения в указанный массив `vr_cr` вот так:

```
select id bulk collect into vr_cr 
from cred where clientID = 28850 and parent_id is null
;
```

Comment: Результат не совсем как вопросе. Если есть желание, дополните чем то  таким: `for i in 1..vr_cr.count loop vc_credits||','||vr_cr(i); end loop;`. Получится 100% ответ на вопрос ТС.